# difficulty with Xcode Static Analyzer showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, clang-static-analyzer

I am using Xcode's static analyzer to find out the potential leaks in my project and it's working absolutely fine. But, sometimes the analyzer is showing a potential leak even after releasing the object. I am finding it difficult to understand this outcome.

Comment: Can you post code snippets that show the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory leaks wont cause you any sort of problem except one.

If you have alot of memory leakage and the assigned memory for your app gets full then your app will crash. and except this situation your app will run perfectly fine. X-code's static analyzer is best for checking memory leaks before you run your code.

check this link too

[Why should we release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761036/why-should-we-release)